# xpath to find the elements which are identical

Tags: css, xpath

I have three filter fields which has the same attribute `[placeholder="Filter..."]` and its a 3rd party library (the devextreme grid library) for which I couldn't add test id for it. How do I find the xpath Query to identify the third element. The Html structure is like below

```
<input class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input Editor-input-547" placeholder="Filter..." type="text" value="">
```

I have tried `'/descendant::input[placeholder="Filter..."][2]'`
or `'input[placeholder="Filter..."][2]'` but it doesn't identify any element. `'[placeholder="Filter..."]'` identifies the first element.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `[2]` with `[3]`?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select *second instance* of element located anywhere in XML-doc try

```
(//input[placeholder="Filter..."])[2]
```

P.S. Note that in XPath indexes starts from`1`, but not from `0` as in most programming language. So `[3]` should be used for *third* and so on...